# Weird Trailing Slash at End of Twitter Message

Tags: twitter, trailing-slash

I am using the following code to show a page with a Twitter box already filled in with a message:

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/share.php?url=http://myurl.com&text=myMessage" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

However, on the page, I am getting this inside the Twitter box:

```
myMessage/
```

Note the trailing slash.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have found a workaround for this, where you add the source=webclient parameter, crucially, to the END of the twitter address. When you do this, Twitter no longer adds the trailing slash. However, given how Twitter like to change their formats and codes around, there's no guarantee this will work forever :-)

For example...

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=http://www.rsc.org%2FEducation%2FEiC%2Fissues%2F2013January%2F50th%2Delement%2Dtin%2Easp&amp;source=webclient" target="_blank">Twitter this</a>
```

Comment: how did you find out? that's so weird!

Comment: This is stupid!!! I'm sharing URL which looks like `http://website.com/page?info=data`. Of course I can't add the tralining slash after `data`, this would broke my URL! :(

Answer (score 5):

No, the solution is more simple. URL-encode your url :

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=myMessage&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com
```

Comment: Nope. My URL encoded, still the same problem. Need to add traling slash, but it's not always possible (if I have get parameters, I can't add the slash after them)

Answer (score 3):

Add a trailing slash to your URL and that should go away. It worked for me.

Change the URL from this:

```
http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://myurl.com&text=myMessage
```

To this:

```
http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://myurl.com/&text=myMessage
```

Answer (score 2):

As Twitter documentation claims ([twitter original reference](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent)):

> A **fully-qualified** URL with a HTTP or HTTPS scheme, URL-encoded.

Fully-qualified URL requires to have trailing slash.
From the same documentation:

> Example Value: http:%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F

Note, that the example has `%2F` at the end, which is HTML encoded `/` character. Twitter tries to create correct URL by appending `/` automatically.

Set your `url` GET parameter to `http://myurl.com/` to get rid of the trailing slash

Comment: This works well. For those finding this question 2 years later like me, try this out. I am dynamically sharing by using ```window.location.origin``` which does not add a trailing slash to the url and caused Twitter to add one to my tweet message. However, doing ```window.location.origin + '/'``` worked.